# how to get variable data out side of when condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i declare a variable name as Result1 this variable i have used in when conditions

so that variable i want to used out side of when condition. facing issues as variable name as OUT of scope , to resolve this issue can we declare a global variable as gblresult.
how we can pass result1 content to gblresult, but i dont know how to implement. kindly suggest me some thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this perhaps what you want?

```
<xsl:variable name="result">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="...">...</xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="...">...</xsl:when>
     ...
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<!-- use variable result here-->
```

Comment: under when condition  i m using another variable since in that  condition <xsl:variable  name="result1" select ="$tag54Avalue"/> it will work?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?